# Is it okay to design a database with columns that could possibly contradict each other

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Suppose I'm designing a database for an insurance company with the following two tables:

**Customers**

```
CustomerID, CustomerName
```

**Policies**

```
PolicyID, CustomerID, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate
```

A customer is considered "Active" if it has a policy such that the expiration date of the policy is after today. Naturally, I expect to build many queries that filter out inactive customers or vice-versa. My debate is whether or not to add a field "Active" to the `Customers` table.

On one hand, this will improve the performance of bunch of my queries and it will look cleaner and easier to understand.

On the other hand, it would have to be updated daily. Also, whether a customer is considered active is completely a function of data in the policy table. So, by adding an "Active" column, I'm creating a potential scenario where a customer is marked as active but his policy data would deem him inactive (or vice-versa). In other words, I'm creating a design where the data could contradict itself.

Is this bad practice?

Comment: I don't see a reason to do that. The query you will make to update the column `Active` will be the same to use when you want to know whether the Customer is active or not. I would not go by this way.

Comment: In what way do you expect this to improve the performance of your queries?  I would think that there is either zero effect, or it would actually slow down your queries.

Comment: Question 1: is nthere a significant performance improvement? Question 2: Can they not be kept in sync in real time? if not, is there a real probability that some query could be wrong if run when they're inconsistent?

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about something like [denormalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)

Comment: I think it's easier to develop if you don't have to join the Policies table every time you want to filter by status, particularly if a customer can have multiple policies (1-to-many vs. 1-to-1)

Comment: It's a classic trade-off question: yes, introducing the `active` column makes your life easier in terms of querying - is it worth it? Are you other queries really that compute-intensive? Does it matter? And just how important is it to your business that this "is a customer active?" answer is always, at any given second, absolutely right? How bad would the consequences be (and how expensive, potentially), if your system would answer "yes!" for a customer, which really isn't active anymore, at 3:34pm on any given business day? It's a trade-off - you need to make + **document** it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As duskwuff says, this is a common practice.

However, denormalization has some costs - you have to come up with an alternative way to keep the "active" column up to date, and that process will introduce more code and therefore opportunities for failure.

In general, I strongly recommend only denormalizing if you know you have a performance problem. The additional join to the Policies table will almost certainly have no measurable impact on your system's performance until you reach hundreds of millions of records. If you're worried, build a test database and use a tool like DBMonster to populate it with test data, and write the queries you need; optimize them as much as possible, and only if you can't get the degree of performance you need should you consider denormalizing.

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is what's known as a *denormalized* database schema. It's a perfectly valid technique to use to improve performance, so long as you can ensure that data remains consistent.

Further reading at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 2):

I will start with noting that the potential query on the policies table *is* expensive (although this can be much ameliorated by proper use of indexes).  You have to look up all the policies for a given customer and determine if any are active.

However, you don't provide enough information to answer this question.

Here are two different scenarios.  Customers add, remove, and modify policies every day all the time.  Most of the database is devoted to the operational problem of keeping data up-to-date.  Most queries are then at the policy level.  Occasionally you need to do some reporting on whether a customer is active for some reason.  Well, in this case, it doesn't seem worth the effort to modify the data structure for "occasional" queries.  The proper focus is being sure the data gets updated.

Alternatively.  The database is loaded nightly and used primarily for reporting purposes on active customers and *not* on their policy details (if you have to join to policies anyway, then you are not saving anything).  There are no intermediate updates and most of the queries look at the customer-level and would use the active flag.  Well, here it seems worth it.

The challenge I have with your situation is you seem to be designing a database both for transactional purposes (highly normalized) and for reporting (often less normalized).  The two don't necessarily mix very well.  Here is a simple reason.  You run an interesting reporting query that takes five minutes.  And during those five minutes, one or more tables are locked for the query.  Or, the query takes an hour, because updates regularly lock the tables that it is using.

I think you need to think more about how the system will be used.  I would recommend that you learn about data marts, especially dimensional marts as described by Ralph Kimball (in his class "The Data Warehouse Toolkit", for instance).  The concept of "data mart" might help.

You should also learn about triggers, which can keep such information up-to-date even in an operational system.  And about computed columns and views, which are ways to access common information not stored directly in columns.

Answer (score 1):

If the criteria you have defined is the only criteria as to them being active, I would say that it is fine to just check on the Policies row for a customer.

In the event that there was a lot more logic or some expensive logic to calculate their active status then it may be better to calculate this as part of a process and store it in an active field in the Customers table.

There could be some other deciding factors, such as those you mention and it's really up to the architect to either test and ensure that one way is better over the other, or to decide they prefer it a specific way due to a steadfast need.

This is just what I have learned from experience and have not really seen any rules that imply otherwise, but that doesn't mean they do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think yes. Your DB design is contradicting.
It is always recommended that you keep DB clean. Also, keep DB at maximum normal form.

Here, instead of updating "Active" flag periodically, you can do one thing. First of all add column "Active Till" in table Customers. than while adding a record in Policies, you need to check that is the [expiration date] in "Customers" table is earlier than [expiration date] in the current record being added. If yes, change it to Date according to "current record for Policies". If not, just don't change it. And when you need to check that whether user is active or not, just read the "Active Till" column and decide.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been is that you add the field then at some point in the future there's a good chance that someone else will get them out of sync.
I worked in a data warehouse for 5 years and this was a common issue that was difficult to deal with.
To address this I would consider doing one of two things - either:

- build a function or stored procedure in the database that will do the calculation using the two date fields

or

- build a function or method in the lanaguage being used that calculates active based on the stored fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would **not** pollute your `Customers` table with a column indicating "active" status.  What you are calling "active" is a "business definition" and might very well change.  Also, such a column only is only meaningful "as of today".  You would need to UPDATE the customer table every day (presumably at midnight) to capture expiring policies and you might need to UPDATE  it when a policy is cancelled.  Plus, your model supports multiple policies for the same customer (a good thing), so maintenance would be awkward.

Also, what if you wanted to find all active customers "as of" the first of last month (a typical query)?  Your "active" status column would be useless.

So, my opinion is: leave it as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from the tone of your question that you already know this is a really bad idea.  You should not consider giving yourself the headache of maintaining two different stores for the same piece of information unless and until you know that you have a performance problem.

The only advantage that your proposed solution provides is that it provides some clarity of expression when attempting to determine whether a customer is active.  To get that clarity of expression without creating the update headache, you can use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerStatus (CustomerID, IsActive) AS
  SELECT CustomerID, (IIF(MAX(ExpirationDate))) >= GET_TODAYS_DATE()
  GROUP BY CustomerID
```

(where IIF() and GET_TODAYS_DATE() are functions specific to whatever database engine you're using).   Now, you can check this table, or JOIN it to Customers, to get the customer's status.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment from @duskwuff...

I'm going through [something simialr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283350/how-can-i-properly-present-and-write-a-checkboxlist-to-a-db-theory-logic-help) at the moment on a MS SQL database and I would recommend entering the following term in Google:

```
Database Normalization -oracle -mysql -db2
```

Naturally, if you're using Oracle or MySql swap out those statements with -microsoft or something of the sort.  Some of this content is a bit dry but it's helped me with organizing a current database project I'm working on.